# Extra argument 'byToken' in call Agora in joinchannel

Tags: swift, agora.io

I generated a token using cpp and followed used their sample code for swift. But it showed an error - Extra argument 'byToken' in call. When i removed byToken, then the error became Extra argument 'uid' in call. How should I fix this error?

```
`func joinChannel() {
        // Set audio route to speaker
        agoraKit.setDefaultAudioRouteToSpeakerphone(true)

        // 1. Users can only see each other after they join the
        // same channel successfully using the same app id.
        // 2. One token is only valid for the channel name that
        // you use to generate this token.

        let uid1: String =  (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!

        agoraKit.joinChannel(byToken: Token, channelId: "channelroom1", info: nil, uid:uid1) { [unowned self] (channel, uid, elapsed) -> Void in
            // Did join channel "demoChannel1"
            self.isLocalVideoRender = true
//            self.logVC?.log(type: .info, content: "did join channel")
        }

        isStartCalling = true
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because **uid** variable has datatype of **UInt**. 
 Following conversion will work.

```
//Mark that I have changed here:UInt(uid)
    mRtcEngine.joinChannel(byToken: token, channelId: channelName, info: extraInfo , uid: UInt(uid)) { (sid, uid, elapsed) in
          self.mRtcEngine.setEnableSpeakerphone(true)
          UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        }
```